# Relative Sort Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am working on a problem on LeetCode and having some troubles

https://leetcode.com/problems/relative-sort-array/

Instructions:
Given two arrays arr1 and arr2, the elements of arr2 are distinct, and all elements in arr2 are also in arr1.

Sort the elements of arr1 such that the relative ordering of items in arr1 are the same as in arr2.  Elements that don't appear in arr2 should be placed at the end of arr1 in ascending order.

Example 1:

Input: arr1 = [2,3,1,3,2,4,6,7,9,2,19], arr2 = [2,1,4,3,9,6]
Output: [2,2,2,1,4,3,3,9,6,7,19]

my attempt:

```
var relativeSortArray = function(arr1, arr2) {
    let arr =[]
    let end =[]
    for (i=0; i<arr2.length; i++){
        for (j=0; j<arr1.length; j++){
            if(arr2[i] == arr1[j]){
                arr.push(arr1[j])
            }else{
                end.push(arr1[j])
            }
        }
    }
    end.sort((a,b) => a-b)
    console.log(end)
    return arr
};
```

The If conditional works but the else condition isn't and I can't figure out why.

I think console.log(end) should give me the two numbers not in arr2 but it instead gives me:

```
[
  1, 1, 1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2, 2, 2, 2,
  2, 2, 2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3, 3, 3, 3,
  3, 3, 3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4, 4, 4, 6,
  6, 6, 6,  6,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7, 7, 9, 9,
  9, 9, 9, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19
]
```

Why is this happening?

Thanks!!!

Comment: your logic is wrong, just iterate through arr1 check if the value is in arr2 by indexOf function

Comment: Your `end` array is that big because in every iteration of `arr2` you're finding the same missing elements over and over again.

Comment: @AkashDathan the results are telling me it is wrong. I don't understand HOW it is wrong. I see it as if they are the same push here, if not push there. Why does that not work?

Comment: @CarlosRoso How is it iterating over everything again?

Comment: First i = 0. Then you go through all the items in `arr1`, find the missing ones, and add them to `end`. Then, i = 1, then you go through all the items in `arr1`, find the missing ones, and add them to `end`. Then, i = 2, then....

Comment: first of all, arr1 should be iterated in the outer loop, and there should not be an else condition in the inner loop. you should be pushing to the end array only if the item does not exist in arr2, so you have to push to the end array after the complete iteration of the inner loop, you can use a flag variable to achieve this.

Comment: the key thing is that the check to push the item to the end array should be there only after the complete iteration of the inner loop, not inside the else block.

Answer (score 4):

You could take an object for the position of a value and take a large value like `Number.MAX_VALUE` as default value. If the delta is zero sort by value.

Taking a delta is a standard by using [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). This returns a value smaller than zero, zero or greater than zero, depending on the values. The sort method receives this values and keeps or swaps the values.

```js
const
    relativeSort = (array, given) => {
        const order = Object.fromEntries(given.map((v, i) => [v, i + 1]));
        return array.sort((a, b) =>
            (order[a] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b] || Number.MAX_VALUE) ||
            a - b
        );
    };

console.log(...relativeSort([2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 2, 19], [2, 1, 4, 3, 9, 6]));
```

Comment: This code does work, could you help me to understand how?

Comment: @AndreTheTallGuy when you use the `.sort` function with a callback, you need a way to tell "`a` goes before `b`". You can't use the values here, your criteria is the position where those values should go. You get that criteria by building an object that maps values vs. positions from `arr2`, like `order = {2: 1, 1: 2, 4: 3, 3: 4, 9: 5, 6: 6}`. Then use those indexes to compare "ah, 3 goes before 9 because `order[3] = 4` and `order[9] = 5`, that means 4-5 < 0, so 3 goes indeed before 9". For numbers without `order` you assume they go in the tail by assigning them an "infinite" position.

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration of `arr2`:
all the numbers that are different from the current number are pushed to the `end` array

For example,

**First iteration** - compare number (2) and you will end up with:

`arr: [2,2,2]`

`end: [3,1,3,4,6,7,9,19]`

**Second iteration** - compare number (1) and you will end up with:

`arr: [2,2,2,1]`

`end: [3,1,3,4,6,7,9,19] + [2,3,3,2,4,6,7,9,2,19]`

try to debug your code to follow the flow

Comment: Why would end equal [3,1,3,4,6,7,9,19] ?

Comment: In the first iteration, you are pushing all the items that are `!=2`

In the second  iteration, you are pushing all the items that are `!=1`

...

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def relativeSortArray(self, arr1: list[int], arr2: list[int]) -> list[int]:
        arr = []
        for i in arr2:
            value = arr1.count(i)
            for j in range(value):
                arr.append(i)
                arr1.remove(i)
        arr1.sort()
        return arr+arr1
obj = Solution()
arr1 = [28,6,22,8,44,17]
arr2 = [22,28,8,6]
result = obj.relativeSortArray(arr1,arr2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but rather explain your approach a little in textual form: Why and how does it work? How does it differ from the other answers given?